# Symfony 4 returns 401 unauthorized error for every request

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I started to work on a project based on Symfony 4, PostgreSQL and PHP7.2. It returns a `401 unauthorized error` for every request. I've checked my database and the .env file, installed composer dependencies, but none signal about the problem's cause.

Answer (score 0):

After testing many possibilities, the solution was to install php7.2-pgsql:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-pgsql
```